# Filter by multiple LDAP groups in Flask App Builder using AUTH_LDAP_SEARCH_FILTER

Tags: airflow, python-ldap, flask-appbuilder

I am configuring the Airflow FAB UI to use LDAP authentication. Currently I have this working, but I can only filter by users who are members of one group in LDAP.

`AUTH_LDAP_SEARCH_FILTER = '(memberOf=CN=group1)'`

I would like to authenticate users who are in one of two groups. I have tried multiple variations of the below in the webserver_config.py

`AUTH_LDAP_SEARCH_FILTER = '|(memberOf=CN=group1)(memberOf=CN=group2)'`

but I am always greeted with this error in the Airflow Webserver logs when trying to log in.

`` ERROR - {`result`: -7, `desc`: `Bad search filter`, `ctrls`: [] } ``

Is filtering by multiple groups possible within the FAB LDAP framework?

Answer (score 2):

Try adding another set of parentheses inside the quotes to encompass the multiple conditions:
AUTH_LDAP_SEARCH_FILTER = '**(**|(memberOf=CN=group1)(memberOf=CN=group2)**)**'